# Substr evaluation followed by curly braces as a loop

Tags: ksh

Following is the code loop which I encountered in one of my korn shell script. I am not sure how it works. When I try to print any statement inside the loop it does not show up on console. I need to debug whether the expression evaluates to true and control goes inside the loop or not.

```
substr{"0000001",1,7} == "0000001"{
    #initializing some variables to 0
    print "Inside substr"
}
```

Comment: is this ksh ? have you tried `echo substr{"0000001",1,7}` in ksh ? is this what you want ?

Comment: except for the curly braces in `substr{}`, which would more commonly be normal parenthesis, that could be `awk` code or some such.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work: that's not valid ksh. You'd need

```
x="000000123"
if [[ "${x:0:7}" = "0000001" ]]; then
    print "inside"
fi
```

The variable is not strictly necessary for functionality.